# Hamburger menu on website not working

Tags: jquery, css, navigationbar

I am using this web template which I downloaded from PixelHint:
http://pixelhint.com/demo/la_casa/

I have uploaded it and started to edit it, when saved on my computer (not on FTP) the hamburger menu works but since uploading it, the hamburger menu when in responsive no longer appears.

My website can be found here: http://daysoutexpert.com/index.html

Comment: Are you referring to the Gear icon, as I can't see any hamburger on the original template or your modified one.

Comment: when you shrink the window for mobile, the top navigation changes to a "hamburger" icon - aka three lines on top of each other. When you click this on the "La Casa" template the menu opens, on my website it doesn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing 2 crucial files
jquery.js and main.js

jquery is the 'infamous' utility library and main.js contains the template specific routines, one of which opens the menu.
I suspect these were included in the original template package.

The browser console also shows these errors
[image]

Comment: You are amazing - thank you so much, I have no idea why those files didn't upload... the 'js' folder did, but not the files! Thank you again!